# Manage User Specific PowerShell Functions in Active Directory Domain

Tags: active-directory, user-management, best-practices, powershell-v4.0

**Given:** Windows Server 2012 R2 / PowerShell 4

**Do need:** a way to manage user/role specific PowerShell functions in an Active Directory domain.

**Do NOT need:** help with coding these scripts. This question is about managing user/role specific PowerShell functions.

**An example:**

1. Developer logs on to his workstation
2. Opens `PowerShell`
3. Issues a command `Start-RemoteDebugger`
4. `msvsmon.exe` starts on his workstation

**Another example:**

1. Developers opens a `remote PowerShell` tab to test server
2. Issues a command `Start-RemoteDebugger`
3. `msvsmon.exe` starts on the test server

What would be the best practises in managing such scripts? Given that only specific users/roles can actually write these scripts.

Comment: If you do some research on Powershell Profiles, you'll learn how they can accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: @Craig620 Thanks a ton. Just didn't know what they'd be called :) I'll do my reading. Thanks.